# why dict.get() doesn't work with another function set as default value?

Tags: python, dictionary

Below are 2 identical functions, but one with dict.get() and another with if key in dict.
On 15, 30 and 45 it must get hashed value, but instead it returns default value - function, even though key is clearly in dictionary already?

```
D = dict()
def bugged(i):
    def nest():
        print('Not in D')
        div, mod = divmod(i, 5)
        D[i] = (div, mod)
        return div, mod
    print()
    print(i)
    print(i in D)
    return D.get(i, nest())


def works(i):
    def nest():
        print('Not in D')
        div, mod = divmod(i, 5)
        D[i] = (div, mod)
        return div, mod
    print()
    print(i)
    print(i in D)
    if i in D:
        return D[i]
    return nest()

f = works
f = bugged

for x in range (0,50,5):
    f(x)
print('='*100)
for x in range (0,50,3):
    f(x)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, arguments are evaluated before the function call, so in your case nest() is being called before D.get. Since nest mutates D, D.get always ends up returning the value set in nest().

Omitting the print statements, your function could be expressed more concisely by using the setdefault dict method:

```
def func(i):
    return D.setdefault(i, divmod(i, 5))
```

Comment: Thanks, I've never seen setdefault used before